# How to get source code from .class file( class file version is 1.2)

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiling, jd-gui

Unresolved compilation problem:

> Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source
>   level is 1.5 or greater

I used JD GUI de-compiler but it is giving above error.

is there any way i can get source code

Comment: Where does this message appear? When you try to DEcompile it? Or when you try to compile the generated source?

Comment: In JD decompiler or all most in all decompilers

Answer (score 2):

Try this at the command line. It will also show the JDK version used to compile the class, in the beginning , like: major version: 52

```
javap -verbose <class name>
```

Comment: I have already a .class file i don't have .java file. i need to refer some code from the .class file but i tried many decompliers, all decompliers are giving error : "Unresolved compilation problems: \n\tSyntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater\n\tSyntax error"

Comment: did you try the command I gave above ? It is run against the class file, not the java file.

Comment: Yes i tried but after running that command same error in the source code

Comment: i.e. Unresolved compilation problems: \n\tSyntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater\n\tSyntax error"

Comment: what is the version of java you have, when you type `javac -version`

Comment: javap -verbose <class name> command is giving major version :46

Comment: i have java 1.8.0_60

Answer (score 1):

Try [javadecompilers.com](http://www.javadecompilers.com/), I've successfully decompiled some class files there.

Comment: same problem : Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tSyntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Comment: Do you get that error from the decompiler, or when you try to recompile the source?

Comment: Because java class version of my .class file is 1.2 ( 46 )

Comment: Yes in decompiler i am getting error. It is not giving full source code from .class file

Comment: Did you try all the different decompilers on the site I linked to? There are six different ones to choose from below the file upload box.